# gcc assembly extended register

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

What parameter/constraint do I have to use in order to tell the compiler to use an extended register pair as the output/input?

```
static inline void mac_dsp(int64_t *c, uint32_t a, uint32_t b){
    //This does not compile - "madd.u [%a15]0,[%a15]0,%d15,%d2: Too many operands"      
    __asm__ ("madd.u  %0,%0,%1,%2" : "+m" (*c) : "d" (a), "d" (b));

    //This does compile but I don't explicitly want to use e2 only but let the compiler 
    //chose which one...
    __asm__ ("madd.u  %%e2,%%e2,%1,%2" : "+m" (*c) : "d" (a), "d" (b));
}
```

Can anyone help me here? Thank you!

Comment: Which architecture is this? Check out [this documentation page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints).

Comment: the microcontroller is a tricore from infineon. the compiler is hightec gcc, (which is basically the same as gcc 4.9.4 i believe)

Comment: What does your compiler's documentation say about register constraints for your architecture?  Tricore is not in the documentation I linked, so it might be something your vendor hacked in.

Comment: **m** memory label; **n** variable or operand is const; **o** a memory operand, but only if address is offsettable; **V** a memory operand that is not offsettable. **<** a memory operand with autodecrement addressing; **>** a memory operand with autoincrement addressing; **F** an immediate floating operand; **g** any register, memory or immediate integer operand, except for registers that are not general registers; **a** address register; **d** data register; and some more integer constants

Comment: I that's all, it seems like you are out of luck.  You might have a chance to get what you want by [pinning local variables to registers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables) but I'm not sufficiently familiar with your architecture to find out if that might be helpful.

Comment: maybe you know how I could force the compiler to use a different assembly instruction so that I do not have to write assembly myself? is that possible? like in my case: instead of madd.u i want to use madd.q

Comment: I'm not familiar with tricore, so I can't really help you with that.  Perhaps try to choose different data types.  For `madd.q` it seems like you might want an `uint64_t`.

Comment: Also, since gcc is GPL, obtain source code for your version and check if there are undocumented constraints.

Comment: Are you sure there's no intrinsic for this, and that the compiler won't use it automatically as a peephole for `*c += a * (uint64_t)b;`?  Does the instruction really need a memory destination, rather than 2 registers?  That's unusual.

Comment: in the manual I did not find an intrinsic function for this no... I am not sure, but I compared to the madd.u and madd instructions and they both use an extended register as the first two arguments. `*c += a*(uint64_t)b` produces madd.u in assembly

Comment: thanks for your helping comments. the final solution how i could reference an extended register was: `__asm__ ("madd.u  %A0,%A0,%1,%2" : "+m" (*c) : "d" (a), "d" (b));`