# gcc extended asm return

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

How can I achieve writing to a pointer destination instead of returning a value from a function call like:

```
/*no return function*/
static inline void mac(int64_t *output, in32_t a, int32_t b){
    __asm__ ("madd %0,%0,%1,%2"       
             //madd E[c],E[d],D[a],D[b] -> E[c]=E[d]+(D[a]*D[b])

            /*OUTPUTS*/
            : "+m" (*output)          
            /*------------------------------------------------------------------
            m as "output" is a pointer to some memory?
            what constraint needs to be here? 
            extended register pair E[c],E[d] is needed in the madd instruction 
            -> c+=a*b is translated to madd %%e6,%%e6,%dX,%dY with X,Y some data
            registers....
            ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

            /*INPUTS*/
            : "r" (a), "r" (b)
            );
}
```

I cannot find this in the online documentation([link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate)).

A problem which also arises when I want to debug, is that the function is not compiled (I cannot step into it), as the compiler probably thinks that nothing is done at all in the function and he just skips it?

Comment: For writing into memory `m` should work. I am confused since you mention registers only. In that case use register output operands and just write them out into memory using C after the asm block.

Comment: Your code seems correct.  Does it not work?

Comment: You [already confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147076/gcc-assembly-extended-register#comment91270572_52147076) that gcc knows how to optimize `*c += a * (uint64_t)b` into `madd.u`, and I assume `*c += a * (int64_t)b` into signed `madd`.  Why do you still want to use inline asm for this?  Is there some missed optimization you're seeing in real code?

Comment: Re: debugging: if the result is unused, it will optimize away.  You could do `volatile int64_t sink = tmp;` or print the result to stop the compiler from optimizing it away.  (Don't use `asm volatile`, you *want* the compiler to be able to optimize in general.)

Comment: it is just an example here, I actually want to use madd.q and somehow i don't get the compiler to use this special instruction. i just took madd as an example here. thanks for your hint about debugging!